# Looping through two worksheet arrays in two workbooks

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to create and loop through two different arrays, each containing 20 worksheets. The worksheets come from two different workbooks, "monthly" and "weekly."

I have the following (after some suggested edits):

```
    Dim Monthly As Excel.Workbook
    Set Monthly = Workbooks("name of monthly workbook")
    Dim Weekly As Excel.Workbook
    Set Weekly = Workbooks.Open("path to weekly workbook")

    Dim mWshtNames As Variant
    Dim mWshtNameCrnt As Variant
    Dim wWshtNames As Variant
    Dim wWshtNameCrnt As Variant

    mWshtNames = Array(Monthly.Worksheets("Reading Monthly"), Monthly.Worksheets("Writing Monthly"), Monthly.Worksheets("Science Monthly"))
'and so on, to include 20 worksheets
    wWshtNames = Array(Weekly.Worksheets("Reading Weekly"), Weekly.Worksheets("Writing Weekly"), Weekly.Worksheets("Science Weekly"))
'and so on, to include 20 worksheets

        For Each mWshtNameCrnt In mWshtNames
            For Each wWshtNameCrnt In wWshtNames
                MsgBox "Monthly sheet is " + mWshtNameCrnt.Name
                MsgBox "Weekly sheet is " + wWshtNameCrnt.Name
                'the real code will loop here; I am using MsgBox to test that the loop is working.
            Next wWshtNameCrnt
        Next mWshtNameCrnt
```

The end goal for the code is to copy data from specific cells in each Weekly worksheet and pasting it into a corresponding cell in a corresponding Monthly worksheet; so the loops need to be like a one-to-one relationship.

Current result (12 msgboxes):

- "Monthly sheet is Reading Monthly", "Weekly sheet is Reading Weekly", "Weekly sheet is Writing Weekly", "Weekly sheet is Science Weekly"
- "Monthly sheet is Writing Monthly", "Weekly sheet is Reading Weekly", "Weekly sheet is Writing Weekly", "Weekly sheet is Science Weekly"
- "Monthly sheet is Science Monthly", "Weekly sheet is Reading Weekly", "Weekly sheet is Writing Weekly", "Weekly sheet is Science Weekly"

Expected result (6 msgboxes):

- "Monthly sheet is Reading Monthly", "Weekly sheet is Reading Weekly"
- "Monthly sheet is Writing Monthly", "Weekly sheet is Writing Weekly"
- "Monthly sheet is Science Monthly", "Weekly sheet is Science Weekly"

The answer by @Jeeped has the same effective result, where the Immediate Window returns nine results where six are expected. I think I need "Next wWshtNameCrnt" and "Next mWshtNameCrnt" to activate at the same time, but do not know how to write this.

Comment: Shouldn't `'and so on, to include 20 workbooks` be `'and so on, to include 20 workSHEETs` ?

Comment: What exactly is your loop supposed to ***do***? If you just want to display the names, you need to call `.Name` on your worksheet instances.

Comment: You should use a `For` loop to iterate arrays, and a `For Each` loop to iterate collections of objects. Your comments indicate that the arrays contain *workbooks*, but your code says otherwise and the arrays actually contain *worksheets*. Also your arrays are storing the `Worksheet` objects, not just their names, so the name of the variable is misleading.... and `mWshtNames` vs `wWshtNames` is hard to read and easy to mistake one for the other. How about `monthlySheets` and `weeklySheets` instead?

Comment: That said, I've no idea what your question is.

Comment: @Jeeped , yes, meant to say workSHEETS. Edited to add this, and to add the context. The code will be copying data from a cell in a given Weekly sheet, and pasting it into a cell in a given Monthly sheet, so I don't just need the names.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us exactly what the specific problem is. Are you getting an error message? What does it say? Or is the nested loop not looping? Or it's looping but not how you'd expect? What are you expecting then? At the moment it's impossible to give you an answer, because there is no question.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Alright, I have made those edits. Currently the code just "doesn't work", and it's hard to give a specific error message because it has been a system of trial and error with many error messages along the way. It has never looped because I don't have the right syntax to loop through worksheets in two workbooks.

Comment: Well your error 438 is because you're trying to add (`+`) a string and a worksheet object together, and VBA doesn't know how to do that. Use the string concatenation operator (`&`) instead, to force the worksheet['s default property - i.e. its name] to be evaluated as a string. OR, keep the `+` operator and make sure both operands *are* `String` expressions, i.e. `"Monthly sheet is: " + mWshtNameCrnt.Name` - and this is where my earlier comment kicks in - you're iterating *worksheet objects*, not *sheet names*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have also tried using "&". Same error message (438). This is what leads me to believe it's a problem of syntax of looping through worksheets in two different workbooks, and that msgbox problems are secondary. I haven't written down every error message I've received in these past three hours of troubleshooting; as I said, it's been trial and error the whole way.

Comment: Ah, that's right - you **need** to concatenate the `.Name` property explicitly regardless of the operator, apparently a `Worksheet` does not have a default property (which is a good thing, tbh). Again your "array of names" does not contain *names*, but *worksheet objects*. Anyway the point is, SO questions need to be *useful*, and to be useful a question needs to be *specific*. Does the answer below not address how to do the loops?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I commented before the edit of your message. Your mWshtNameCrnt.Name method is working - just not how I expected it to. I'm testing with three worksheets for right now, as demonstrated above. The loop should be returning six values, where Lorem is tied to Sit, Ipsum is tied to Amet, and Dolor is tied to Consectetur. Instead, it is turning nine values: Lorem > Sit, Amet, Consectetur, Ipsum > Sit, Amet, Consectetur, and Dolor > Sit, Amet, Consectetur. I'm not sure how to set up that kind of loop.

Comment: Ok, let me suggest something. Drop the lorem ipsum stuff, and give us something clear - monthly sheets could be "Jan", "Feb", "March", then weekly could be "Wk1", "Wk2", "Wk3" - then you can describe what you're expecting vs what you're getting (in your post, not in the comments) - again consider [Jeeped's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42374352/1188513), which most certainly does what you need.

Comment: FWIW, the question about how to create an array of "worksheets which also needs to specify the workbook" isn't really meaningful - your code already does that.  If you need to get back to the `Workbook` from a `Worksheet` reference, just call `.Parent`.

Comment: @Comintern I understand your point, but I did not know that my code was already doing this properly when I made the question, and assumed that I was doing something wrong. Either way, original question has been edited for the current/expected result.

Comment: Awesome edit (downvote retracted)! However the "current result" doesn't add up with the loop code in the question, apparently you have the monthly msgbox outside the weekly loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *so the loops need to be like a one-to-one relationship.*

Therefore a nested loop won't do. When you iterate each item in the outer loop, the inner loop iterates all its items *every time the outer loop makes a new iteration* which, to borrow your table relationships vocabulary, would be a *one-to-many* relationship.

If it's "one to one", then you only need 1 loop, and your two arrays have the same size. So make a `For` loop that goes from `LBound(anyOfTheseArrays) To UBound(anyOfTheseArraysButPreferablyTheSameYouUseToGetTheLBound)`:

```
Dim index As Long
For index = LBound(mWshtNames) To UBound(mWshtNames)
    Debug.Print mWshtNames(index).Name, wWshtNames(index).Name
Next
```

For 3 items in each array, that will give you 3 lines output to the *immediate* pane (Ctrl+G), which is much more practical than `MsgBox` calls, at least for debugging.

Comment: Ninja'd me by 47 seconds!  :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to loop through the monthly worksheets and for each, loop through the weekly worksheets.

```
Option Explicit

Sub bleh()
    Dim Monthly As Excel.Workbook, Weekly As Excel.Workbook

    Set Monthly = Workbooks("name of monthly workbook")
    Set Weekly = Workbooks.Open("path to weekly workbook")

    Dim m As Long, w As Long
    Dim mWshtNames As Variant, wWshtNames As Variant

    'define 20 monthly workSHEET names
    mWshtNames = Array("Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor", "sit", "amet", _
                       "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "Sed", "vel", _
                       "cursus", "purus", "Vivamus", "nec", "ex", _
                       "et", "lorem", "fringilla", "consectetur", "Fusce")
    'define 20 weekly workSHEET names
    wWshtNames = Array("Pellentesque", "quis", "viverra", "lorem", "ac", _
                       "sodales", "turpis", "Morbi", "in", "vulputate", _
                       "lectus", "Donec", "aliquam", "suscipit", "nunc", _
                       "eget", "bibendum", "augue", "interdum", "porta")

        For m = LBound(mWshtNames) To UBound(mWshtNames)
            With Monthly.Worksheets(mWshtNames(m))
                Debug.Print .Name
                For w = LBound(wWshtNames) To UBound(wWshtNames)
                    With Weekly.Worksheets(wWshtNames(w))
                        Debug.Print .Name
                    End With
                Next w
            End With
        Next m

End Sub
```

This loops through each monthly worksheet and sends its [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) to the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx). While that monthly worksheet is 'active' it loops through all of the weekly worksheets and send their .Name to the Immediate window.

While the code does nothing purposeful, it calls the name from a process that uses the name so at the very least it verifies the name.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the nested loops entirely.  The worksheets correspond to each other by *subject*, but only coincidentally by name.  Instead of generating all of the complete names (and\or worksheets) before you enter your loop, create the *indexes* by combining the subject and the type of worksheet and get the `Worksheet` reference ***inside*** the loop:

```
Dim Monthly As Excel.Workbook
Set Monthly = Workbooks("name of monthly workbook")
Dim Weekly As Excel.Workbook
Set Weekly = Workbooks.Open("path to weekly workbook")

Dim subjects() As String
subjects = Split("Reading,Writing,Science", ",")
Dim weeklySheet As Worksheet
Dim monthlySheet As Worksheet

Dim subject As String
For Each subject In subjects
    Set weeklySheet = Weekly.Worksheets(subject & " Weekly")
    Set monthlySheet = Montly.Worksheets(subject & " Monthly")
    MsgBox "Monthly sheet is " + monthlySheet.Name
    MsgBox "Weekly sheet is " + weeklySheet.Name
    '"Real" code here.
Next
```

Note that this also allows you to use strongly typed references like `Worksheet` and `String` instead of having to declare everything as `Variant`.